# Spring Boot REST API/Spring Security: Return custom message when authentication fails

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, spring-boot, jersey

I have a Spring Boot app using Jersey as the JAX-RS implementation. This is my security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired TokenAuthenticationProvider tokenAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationTokenFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/dataHub/**")
                .authenticated();
    }
}
```

What I want to be able to do is to have a way to catch the Exceptions thrown by my TokenAuthenticationProvider and convert them into a standardized JSON format that we have agreed upon. Is there a way to do this? I tried messing around with adding a custom AuthenticationFailureHandler, but couldn't get that to work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter appraoch**

The `HttpSecurity` class has a method called [exceptionHandling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#exceptionHandling--) which can be used to override the default behavior. The following sample presents how the response message can be customized.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        // your custom configuration goes here
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, e) -> {
            String json = String.format("{\"message\": \"%s\"}", e.getMessage());
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(json);                
        });
}
```

**@ControllerAdvice appraoch - Why it doesn't work in this case**

At first I thought about `@ControllerAdvice` that catches authentication exceptions for the entire application.

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;

@ControllerAdvice
public class AuthExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
    @ExceptionHandler(AuthenticationException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleAuthenticationException(AuthenticationException e) {
        return String.format("{\"message\": \"%s\"}", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

In the example above, the JSON is built manually, but you can simply return a POJO which will be mapped into JSON just like from a regular REST controller. Since Spring 4.3 you can also use [@RestControllerAdvice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestControllerAdvice.html), which is a combination of `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ResponseBody`.

**However, this approach doesn't work** because the exception is thrown by the `AbstractSecurityInterceptor` and handled by [ExceptionTranslationFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#exceptiontranslationfilter) before any controller is reached.